# Scanning multiple strings in one line to a pointers array in C

Tags: c, strings, array, pointers

I'm trying to write a code for a function that takes an empty array of pointers and its length n.
And scans n strings of max length of MAX_LEN (a defined constant) until a new line is given by the user.
The strings are separated by one space.

```
int scan_strings(char * words[], int n) {
    char current = getchar(); // to make sure that there is no new line
    int i = 0, j = 0, on = 1;
    while (scanf("%c",&current) == 1 && (current != '\n' || on)) {
        char str[MAX_LEN]; // a defined constant
        on = 0;
        if (current != ' ') {
            str[i] = current;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            str[i] = 0;
            i = 0;
            *(words+j) = &str;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

For some reason, the array after writing "foxes are red"
is just:

0x002b8f0c "red" 
0x002b8f0c "red" 
"ERROR READING CHARACTERS" 
"ERROR READING CHARACTERS" 
"ERROR READING CHARACTERS" 
...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing **working** code. Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When the code works then feel free to [edit] the post to include it for a review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is line `*(words+j) = &str;`. It says that we want `words[j]` or `*(words+j)` to point to where the `str` is pointing. So, at the end of the `while`, all the `words` are pointing to the same str with the content of `red`. It can be solved using `strcpy` method from `string.h` header, which copies the values not simply change the reference.

```
strcpy(*(words + j), str);
```

or

```
strcpy(words[j]), str);
```

If you don't want to use string header, you can copy the characters in `str` into the `words[j]` manully.

Also, you have to handle the last string before the new line character. One way is putting the `str` definition out of the `while`, and repeat the copy procedure after the `while` statement once more like this:

```
    } // end of the while
str[i] = '\0';
strcpy(words[j], str);
```

My preferred way to solve this question is:

```
int readLine(char *line)
{
    int spaces = 0;
    char *p = line;
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == ' ')
            spaces++;
        *p++ = c;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return spaces + 1;
}

void strSave(char **buf, char *line)
{
    char *p = line, *q = line;
    int i = 0;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == ' ') {
            buf[i] = malloc((p - q + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strncpy(buf[i], q, p-q);
            p++;
            i++;
            q = p;
        } else {
            p++;
        }
    }
    buf[i] = malloc((p - q + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(buf[i], q, p-q);

}

int main()
{
    char **buf;
    char line[1024];
    int stringCounts;
    char c;

    stringCounts = readLine(line);
    buf = malloc((stringCounts) * sizeof(char *));

    strSave(buf, line);

    for (int k = 0; k < stringCounts; k++) {
        printf("%s\n", buf[k]);
        free(buf[k]);
    }

    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Happy to explain it more if someone's interested.
I know this question was off-topic, but couldn't resist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw why is stringCounts used as an argument for strSave if it's never used?

Comment: It was for the previous version. I'll edit it. Thanks